# Reading .parquet file from spark throwing exceptions when empty

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

While reading .parquet file as below:

```
src = spark.read.parquet(filePath)
```

When file is empty is throwing below error:

```
filename.parquet is not a Parquet file (too small length: 0)
```

How to check if the file is empty before reading?

Comment: Does `not a Parquet file` mean an `empty file` here in `parquet`?

Comment: Could be that the directory `filePath` is empty?